# Создание пользовательской клавиатуры на Android

Tags: java, android

Следую [вот этому уроку](http://goo.gl/6AA0kS). Все получилось, видоизменил клавиатуру, при этом осталось несколько вопросов. Как изменить фон клавиш в классе **Keyboard**? Метод `public void swipeDown()` и другие - как они работают, кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для изменения фона клавиш у класса `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView` есть XML аттрибут `android:keyBackground`.
2. Методы `swipeDown`, `onText`, `onPress` и остальные вызываются классом `KeyboardView` когда происходит соответствующее действие(нажатие на кнопку, ввод последовательности символов).
   Если интересно как именно работает внутри `KeyboardView` - можно посмотреть на [гитхабе](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java), начиная с метода

```
public void setOnKeyboardActionListener(OnKeyboardActionListener listener)
{
    mKeyboardActionListener = listener;
}
```

и далее поиском по `mKeyboardActionListener`.